# Ansible register variable to log file

Tags: redhat, yum, ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to run the a yum list updates command and output the result to a file on the local server. This would be scaled out to run on multiple servers. I have found the local_action module, however this results in an unreadable file. I have found the -debug: var: result command to show the necessary information in a good format, but there doesn't seem to be a way to dump that into a file.

Below is the playbook:

```
---
- hosts:  localhost
  tasks:
  - name: List all available updates
    yum:
      list: updates
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
  - local_action:
      module: copy
      content: "{{ result.results }}"
      dest: "/root/yumlist.yml"
```

The debug task returns a result like this:
*

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "results": [
            {
                "arch": "x86_64", 
                "envra": "0:firefox-68.4.1-1.el7_7.x86_64", 
                "epoch": "0", 
                "name": "firefox", 
                "release": "1.el7_7", 
                "repo": "rhel-7-server-rpms", 
                "version": "68.4.1", 
                "yumstate": "available"
            }, 
            {
                "arch": "x86_64", 
                "envra": "0:fribidi-1.0.2-1.el7_7.1.x86_64", 
                "epoch": "0", 
                "name": "fribidi", 
                "release": "1.el7_7.1", 
                "repo": "rhel-7-server-rpms", 
                "version": "1.0.2", 
                "yumstate": "available"
            },
```

and the local_action gives me this...

[{"envra": "0:firefox-68.4.1-1.el7_7.x86_64", "name": "firefox", "repo": "rhel-7-server-rpms", "epoch": "0", "version": "68.4.1", "release": "1.el7_7", "yumstate": "available", "arch"
    : "x86_64"}, {"envra": "0:fribidi-1.0.2-1.el7_7.1.x86_64", "name":

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the json or yaml output and just want to look nicer there are a couple filters you could try (to_nice_json, or to_nice_yaml) [Ref](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data).

```
  - local_action:
      module: copy
      content: "{{ result.results |to_nice_json }}"
      dest: "/root/yumlist.yml"
```

or

```
  - local_action:
      module: copy
      content: "{{ result.results |to_nice_yaml }}"
      dest: "/root/yumlist.yml"
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and get back to you, jason and yaml are fine.